# How do you debug HFP SCO connections?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, hfp

I am writing an application implementing the HF side of the Bluetooth Hands-free Protocol, and I need some advice as to how you are supposed to debug the SCO connections.

From my assumption and observation, the AG only establishes an SCO connection once a call has been answered (or when one is incoming due to In-band ringtone). This is hard to debug as I don't have a second mobile phone to call myself.

Is there some way to make the phone establish an SCO link without using some service to call the device, or without calling someone yourself?

I know that the HF can ask the AG to establish an SCO link through AT+BCC, but once the socket is open, the AG closes it fairly quickly, which doesn't happen when the AG opens the link on its own.

My approach thus far was an online service that calls me on my mobile phone, but that service only allows 5 calls a day, which I most of the time easily exceed.
The device is an Android phone.

Comment: Some companies such as [Ellisys](https://www.ellisys.com/) and [FTE](https://fte.com/) offer special testing equipment. For example: [Audio Expert System](https://fte.com/products/audioexpert.aspx) from FTE

Comment: @Risto unfortunately this is a personal side-project, so industrial grade testing equipment is kind of out of the question for me.

Comment: Then I would think of a VoIP solution. Setup a SIP PBX and install a VoIP App on your mobile. That would allow endless calls ...